# How do you handle extra strings lines added by translators?

Tags: android, internationalization, translation

I recently started getting translations into 5 languages for an app I'm working on. When I got the translated strings back, there were a bunch of extra lines added around any tags like `<b>` or `xliff:g`. In cases where the text before/after the tag was not a space (e.g. it was punctuation), the extra line causes Android to show an extra space. For example, consider the following string in English:

```xml
<string name="welcome_title">Welcome to <xliff:g id="app_name">App Name</xliff:g>!</string>
```

Pretty simple, right? When a `TextView` displays this in English, it obviously shows the desired result:

> Welcome to App Name!

However, two separate translators (through the Play Store translation service) have now given me back translations that look like the following, e.g. in Spanish:

```xml
<string name="welcome_title">
  Bienvenido a
  <xliff:g id="app_name">App Name</xliff:g>
  !
</string>
```

which causes a `TextView` displaying this text to show an extra space between "App Name" and the exclamation point:

> Bienvenido a App Name !

Practically, this means I have to manually inspect/edit *all* of the thousands of lines of translations done for me to make sure there aren't extra spaces. Not only is it extremely annoying, but in cases like Arabic, I have no clue how correct any spacing is and it's really hard to know I'm editing correctly.

Has anyone come up with a way to prevent this from happening or clean it up quickly when it does happen? I couldn't find anything on this, but it's early and maybe I haven't had enough coffee! I can't be the only one who's had to deal with this.